# Advanced usage of pdfgrep

Tags: pdf, grep

I need help to solve a situation. It's seems rather simple, but it's not I guess.

```
#!/bin/bash

pdfgrep -Hn $1 *.pdf

exit 0
```

If I run this code in any directory containing ocr'd PDF-files it will spit out "matching file+page number in that file+matching line for the pattern $1".

Now to the problem. Say I want to do the same thing with 2 patterns "$1" and "$2". It will not be as easy as

```
pdfgrep -Hn $1 | pdfgrep -Hn $2 *.pdf
```

How could this be done, so that the result will be "matching file+page number in that file containing both patterns $1 **and** $2"?

Any help appreciated:-)

Thank you!

/Paul

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution that's quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdfgrep -Hn $1 *.pdf | cut -f1,2 -d':' > /tmp/sok1.tmp
pdfgrep -Hn $2 *.pdf | cut -f1,2 -d':' > /tmp/sok2.tmp
comm -1 -2 --nocheck-order /tmp/sok1.tmp /tmp/sok2.tmp

exit 0
```

/Paul

Comment: Correction: "comm -2 --nocheck-order /tmp/sok1.tmp /tmp/sok2.tmp"

Comment: Correction2: For some reason this "comm" is not consistant. So then I changed last line to : "grep -f /tmp/sok1.tmp /tmp/sok2.tmp" and it worked!!!